# Is it more acceptable to call jQuery functions in the footer or enqueue in functions in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, performance

Massive hat tip to the community, here, you folks are my go-to most days!

I think my topic says it all, really, with relation to jQuery in WordPress - I've been thinking a lot lately that placing jQuery commands in functions.php would make the effects happen sooner rather than in placing them in footer.php which would be a good thing, I think. Can anyone see any flaws with this approach?

-Jc

Comment: Primarily opinion-based. Its again matter of preference (mother or daughter). My personal opinion: footer (or bottom). Google loves that.

Comment: My personal preference: before close of the `body` tag, so they're loaded last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is primarily opinion based. However, the proper way to include JavaScript files in WordPress is to properly "enqueue" them using the [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function, from the `'wp_enqueue_scripts'` action hook.

To speed up page load, many people prefer to enqueue scripts in the footer, using the 4th and final parameter of `wp_enqueue_script()`.

Doing the following will ensure that your script is properly enqueued, that it's dependencies have been satisfied, and that it's in the footer (added via `wp_footer()`):

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue a script with a jQuery dependency, in the footer
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

For more reasons about *why* you should use this function instead of hard-coding them into the footer of your theme, check out [this post on WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49098/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-wp-enqueue-script).

Comment: rnevius - that makes sense & is the direction that I've been leaning, both your answer & the one that Chip answered on the other post make perfect sense to me.  Much obliged!